# How to Remember application association for this type of file Kubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, kubuntu

I have Kubuntu and I work on website development.

Then I work with file Html and I want open this file with `Kwrite`.

`Kwrite` is an editor and now I always (with two click on this) with `Rekonq` (browser's **kubuntu**)

If I change the open's remember application association for this type of file:

I do it in 3 steps:

1. I right click on the file and choose Open With->Other... from the menu that appears. A list of applications appears.
2. I  Select the default application Kwrite.
3. I Select the Remember application association for this type of file checkbox.

But this does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `mimeopen` followed by the extension you want to change (in this case`.html`):

```
mimeopen .html
```

You will get something similar to this:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type text/html

    1) winebrowser  (wine-extension-htm)
    2) Chromium Web Browser  (chromium-browser)
    3) Google Chrome  (google-chrome)
    4) Firefox Web Browser  (firefox)
    5) Geany  (geany)
    6) notepad  (wine-extension-txt)
    7) gedit  (gedit)
    8) LibreOffice 4.0 Writer  (libreoffice4.0-writer)
    9) Other...

use application #
```

Enter the last number in the list (the one next to `Other...`, in this case `9`) and press enter.  When you get the prompt:

```
Use command:
```

Enter `/usr/bin/kwrite` and press enter.

All `.html` files should now open in Kwrite.

Comment: This not function because not exchange in all file

Comment: @MirkoCianfarani I don't really understand what you mean by that..  What "function" are you referring to?

Comment: That I want to configure the open all file *.html with Kwrite.
I changed Mimeopen and the list of applications that can open this file type.
But more (again ) when I open the file (for example) index.html .
This is opened with Rekonq and not with Kwrite

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the file type you wish to associate with kwrite
2. enter the file **properties**
3. under the **general tab** click "**file type options**"
4. now you will see a list of applications that can open this file type

   - move each one up or down depending on your personal preference.

(please note, i use KDE - this answer works!)

Comment: Sorry 
I delete Rekonq on the applications(4) but I have the problem...
This not function....

Comment: use dolphin to find the file

Comment: I always use Dolphin!!!!

Comment: That I want to configure the open all file *.html with Kwrite.
I changed Mimeopen and the list of applications that can open this file type.
But more (again ) when I open the file (for example) index.html .
This is opened with Rekonq and not with Kwrite